# Jackson requires @JsonSubTypes-property on concrete class in JAX-RS endpoint

Tags: java, inheritance, jackson, mapping, jax-rs

I have multiple JAX-RS endpoints, which work in principle and are reachable, requiring different parameters in the form of Java DTOs.
These DTOs are structured like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "jsonTypeInfo")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = com.company.package.ChildDto.class, name = "ChildDto"),
})
public class ParentDto...
```

Child DTO:

```
public class ChildDto extends ParentDto...
```

Another DTO uses the child DTO directly as property

```
public class OtherDto {
    private ChildDto childDtoRef;
    // getters and setters
```

The endpoint method looks like this

```
@POST
@Path("/my-path")
public void methodName(OtherDto otherDto) {
```

Please note that both DTOs are not marked as abstract (should IMO not make a difference) and that by using the OtherDto, the endpoint directly uses the ChildDto, not ParentDto class. The endpoint works if `"jsonTypeInfo": "ChildDto"` is part of the request body. However, in this case it should not be necessary, since the method only accepts the child class anyway.

If I omit the `"jsonTypeInfo"` property in the JSON of the request body, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple
type, class com...ChildDto]: missing type id property &#x27;jsonTypeInfo&#x27; (for
POJO property &#x27;childDtoRef&#x27;)
at [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 8, column: 5] (through reference chain:
...
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is my expectation, that the jsonTypeInfo property is unnecessary, wrong? Jackson should never need to resolve a ParentDto instance anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out a way to globally configure the behaviour I wanted, but rather found a workaround. On [this site](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) of the jackson repo, it states

> All instances of annotated type and its subtypes use these settings
> (unless overridden by another annotation)

Meaning that `ChildDto` inherits the same `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubtypes` annotation, transitively also requiring the ID property `jsonTypeInfo` to be present.

The workaround therefore is to overwrite the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation with the same content, but added `defaultImpl`, which is an

> Optional property that can be used to specify default implementation
> class to use for deserialization if type identifier is either not
> present [...]

Specifically, add the following annotation to your ChildDto class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "jsonTypeInfo",
        defaultImpl = ChildDto.class)
```